# Edit a job field with P4 cmd (Perforce)

Tags: perforce, jobs

I'm trying to find how to edit a specific job field using p4.exe command line.
I tried to watch the output of P4V when I edit one manually, but it give no advice else than:

*p4 job -i
Job job0001 saved.
p4 job -o job0001*

I tried many commands like: *p4 job -i job0001 filed_name= value , ...*

As usual, the doc explain nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the '-i' flag with the 'p4 job' command, allows a job specification to be read in from a file, if you also use the '<' operator.

For example, I have a standard description, that I want to include in all my jobs, so I run:

p4 job -o > job file

to create a file that contains a job spec.

I then edit this file, so that the 'Description' field contains my description.

I then run the following:

bash-3.2$ p4 job -i < jobfile
  Job job000003 saved.

Running the following command, shows that 'job000003' contains the description, that I wrote in 'job file':

bash-3.2$ p4 job -o job000003
  # A Perforce Job Specification.
  #
  #  Job:         The job name.  'new' generates a sequenced job number.
  #  Status:      Either 'open', 'closed', or 'suspended'. Can be changed.
  #  User:        The user who created the job. Can be changed.
  #  Date:        The date this specification was last modified.
  #  Description: Comments about the job.  Required.

Job:  job000003

Status:   open

User: jen

Date: 2015/03/31 12:08:16

Description:
    My test job.

Hope this helps,
Jen!